# how to detect connection close from remote host

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I've tried to detect connection close from peer application that is in the other computer but in same network.

I used `Socket.Select()` and it worked to peer application in local peer but not to that is on remote host. (I used also `Socket.Recv` and `Socket.Poll` to get FIN)

Select randomly returns and sometimes doesn't return. (Poll too)
What makes this difference?

Receiving other messages is Ok, so network is not a cause.
Only FIN doesn't come!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer guys!!!

Windows doesn't kill process right after we click x on window tab.
We have to detect x button input and terminate process completely to ensure that process is dead.

You can see "undead" processes on your process manager~